# Integer Counter function

Tags: php, arrays

My task is to write a function intCounter($array, $countZeroes = true).
My echo has to display 'array has 4 integers', 
If $countZeroes is 'false', it displays 'array has 1 integers'.

```
$array = 
[ 
  1111,
  'D',     
   0,     
   0,     
   0 
];

function intCounter($array, $countZeroes = true){

}
```

Comment: What is your expected result? Because the question is not really clear..

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far? Show us.

Comment: @Slobodan, could you edit your question and title to make it clearer as to what you are/were trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes. I did it now. 
Let me know id it makes more sense. And thank you for respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use array_filter to discard items we don't want:

```
<?php

$things =
    [ 
        1111,
        'D',
        0,
        0,
        0
    ];

$integers          = array_filter($things, 'is_int');
$non_zero_integers = array_filter($integers);

var_dump($integers);
var_dump($non_zero_integers);

printf("Integers: %s\n", implode($integers, ','));
```

Output:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => int 1111
  2 => int 0
  3 => int 0
  4 => int 0
array (size=1)
  0 => int 1111
Integers: 1111,0,0,0
```

Or write your own condition:

```
$positive_naturals = array_filter($things, function($v) {
    return is_int($v) && $v > 0;
});
```

To count 0 values:

```
print array_count_values($things)[0];
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options to do it!

For example you can do it simply by counting in  a loop:

```
function intCounter1($array, $countZeroes = true) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_int($value) && ($countZeroes || $value != 0)) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Or by filtering the array

```
function intCounter2($array, $countZeroes = true) {
    $array = array_filter($array, function ($value) {
                return (is_int($value));
            });
    if (!$countZeroes) {
        $array = array_filter($array, function ($value) {
            return ($value != 0);
        });
    }
    return count($array);
}
```

For my own opinion the simplest solution is better...

Answer (score 0):

Your question (whether you realize it or not) is actually unclear / too broad because there are many ways to tackle this question and the values that you consider to be valid ("keepers") based on type will dictate the correct method to employ.

Here are some relevant functions that you might consider calling.  You will need to consider the consequences of these methods and do a simple if statement at the start of your `intCounter()` function to dictate which method will provide the desired output.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b9bb43332726e039bb5d0cce9d5b38523d8499c))

```
function retainNumbers($array,$allow_zeros=true){
    echo "This is using array_filter's default behavior:\n";
    var_export(array_filter($array));
    echo "\nThis is array_filter() using is_int():\n";
    var_export(array_filter($array,'is_int'));
    echo "\nThis is array_filter() using is_numeric():\n";
    var_export(array_filter($array,'is_numeric'));
    echo "\nThis is array_filter() using is_integer():\n";
    var_export(array_filter($array,'is_integer'));
    echo "\nThis is array_filter() using ctype_digit():\n";
    var_export(array_filter($array,'ctype_digit'));
    echo "\nThis is preg_grep() with a pattern matching numbers only:\n";
    var_export(preg_grep('/^\d+$/',$array));
    echo "\nThis is preg_grep() with a pattern matching numbers that are not zero:\n";
    var_export(preg_grep('/^[1-9]\d*$/',$array));
}
$array=[1111,-1,'D','','0',10,0,null,.5];
retainNumbers($array);
```

Output:

```
This is using array_filter's default behavior:
array (
  0 => 1111,
  1 => -1,
  2 => 'D',
  5 => 10,
  8 => 0.5,
)
This is array_filter() using is_int():
array (
  0 => 1111,
  1 => -1,
  5 => 10,
  6 => 0,
)
This is array_filter() using is_numeric():
array (
  0 => 1111,
  1 => -1,
  4 => '0',
  5 => 10,
  6 => 0,
  8 => 0.5,
)
This is array_filter() using is_integer():
array (
  0 => 1111,
  1 => -1,
  5 => 10,
  6 => 0,
)
This is array_filter() using ctype_digit():
array (
  0 => 1111,
  4 => '0',
)
This is preg_grep() with a pattern matching numbers only:
array (
  0 => 1111,
  4 => '0',
  5 => 10,
  6 => 0,
)
This is preg_grep() with a pattern matching numbers that are not zero:
array (
  0 => 1111,
  5 => 10,
)
```

It is even possible that no single php function will filter out all of the values that you desire.  In this case you will have to make a two-part conditional filter.  (Again, I can't confidently spoon-feed this to you, because your question is unclear about what to retain.)

It might look like this:

```
function retainNumbers($array,$allow_zeros=true){
    // return preg_grep($allow_zeros?'/^\d+$/':'/^[1-9]\d*$/',$array);  or...
    if($allow_zeros){
        return array_filter($array,'is_int');
    }else{
        return array_filter($array,function($v){return is_int($v) && $v>0;});
    }
}
$array=[1111,-1,'D','','0',10,0,null,.5];
//var_export(retainNumbers($array));
var_export(retainNumbers($array,false));  // how to call with no zeros
```

Answer (score -1):

Loop through and use array_search with 0 (int value) as the needle.  If we find a match we can unset the element with the returned key.

If an array value is 0 (zero) it will match, if it's a string such as 'A' compared to an int it will be automatically cast to int (0) and match.

This will leave non-zero integers (from your example input).

```
<?php
$array = 
[ 
  1111,
  'D',
   0,
   0,
   0,
];

while(true) {
    $key = array_search(0, $array);
    if ($key === false) break;
    unset($array[$key]);
}
var_dump(count($array)); // How many integers in array.
var_dump($array);
```

Output:

```
    int 1
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 1111
```

Comment: The condition 0 == '1' would evaluate to false.  And if there were non-integers such as 1.5 these would also remain.

Comment: Surely a more efficient method would be to loop through all members and use a conditional to filter the original array.